# Why does IIS require mime-types to be declared?

Tags: iis-7, web, mime-types, mime, iis-express

In one of my assignments I was trying to render an SVG image.  It took me some time to come across one link which states that, in order for IIS express to render an SVG image, you have to include the following code in your web.config file

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

It worked.  But I don't understand why/how?  Previously I thought that the server should send the correct Content-Type header.  But my svg code was in Javascript.  I thought (maybe wrongly) that IIS sends only HTML files to the client side, and those HTML files have the Javascript linked in the header.  So, does that mean that IIS is scanning all the javascript files associated with the HTML too? That seems a little hard to believe.  If I have 10 javascript files in my HTML main file, and one of them has an SVG file in it, does that mean IIS will scan all of them, and then find out SVG is missing?  Is this how it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your browser hits a URL, it initially only downloads the HTML.  For every linked file (Javascript, images, CSS, SVG, etc), the browser will make a separate request to the server.  And as you noted, IIS won't serve those files unless it recognizes the MIME type.

To answer your question, no, that's not how it works.  IIS doesn't *scan* the HTML files, it just responds passively to requests from the client (browser).  It's the browser that parses the HTML and Javascript, and executes the Javscript, making an additional round-trips back to the server for linked resources as needed.

*Edit*

The purpose of MIME types for IIS is twofold:

1. Restrict access to the server's resources.  If the client request a Web.config file, then of course IIS should block that request, because the file is likely to contain sensitive information like passwords.
2. Keep track of how to process each file type.  For example, HTML files should generally just be sent, but ASPX files need to be processed first by ASP.Net, and then sent.

Comment: Makes much more sense now. I have one question, if I just included the js file in the header, now browser will go to server and parse HTML, and then there is a javascript associated with it, so the browser is smart enough to make a request by himself and go to the javascript? (Sorry for my ignorance, I am just trying to understand the underlying principle)..

Comment: @UnderDog exactly, the browser is smart enough to go get the Javascript.  HTML, Javascript, SVG are all client-side technologies; it's the browser's job to parse, process, and render them.

Comment: Okay that clear most of the doubts. One last thing I want to ask is, the role of IIS in this, what I mean is, that since it is the work of browser to render/parse HTML, javascript, svg, if my browser is supporting svg, then why IIS needs seperate mimetype. Is IIS acting as a middle-man between the client and server?

Comment: @UnderDog Yes, I suppose you could say IIS is sort of the middle-man in this case.  It's partly a security thing.  Please see my updated answer.